# ASA 5508X to a Modem that only provides LAN

Tags: cisco, routing, internet, lan

I am VERY new to networking but how does an ASA5508X need to be configured to talk to a Modem that has only 1 LAN port on it? I have to configure an "outside" ip and subnet. MY ISP is only able to provide an IP address but no subnet. When I plug directly into the modem I get a 192.168.0.X address. I should mention that this modem uses a SIM to provide internet if that matters.

Help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to configure the ASA in "transparent mode."  That way, the ASA acts as a layer 2 device and needs no addressing.  Connect the outside interface to the modem, and the inside to your switch/host.